# Configure a filter in Java

Tags: java, spring, configuration, spring-boot, prerender

I am trying to follow instructions and configure a prerender filter for Spring Boot but since there is no web.xml in Boot I need to do this with Java configurations.

**Instructions for Spring applications with web.xml that I am trying to follow:**

1: Add this line to your web.xml:

```
<filter>
      <filter-name>prerender</filter-name>
      <filter-class>com.github.greengerong.PreRenderSEOFilter</filter-class>
      <init-param>
          <param-name>prerenderToken</param-name>
          <param-value>[get from prerender: https://prerender.io/]</param-value>
      </init-param>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
      <filter-name>prerender</filter-name>
      <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
```

2: add dependency on your project pom:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.github.greengerong</groupId>
  <artifactId>prerender-java</artifactId>
  <version>1.6.4-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

**What I did so far:**

I added the dependency to the pom. I created a WebConfig class and instantiated the Bean:

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfig {
    @Bean
    public PreRenderSEOFilter PreRenderSEOFilter() {
        PreRenderSEOFilter prerenderFilter = new PreRenderSEOFilter();
        return prerenderFilter;
    }
}
```

But I don't know how to configure it. The `prerenderFilter` has a method `init(FilterConfig filterConfig)`. But I'm not sure how to use it.

How do I configure this prerenderFilter?

Comment: http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-boot/current/api/org/springframework/boot/context/embedded/FilterRegistrationBean.html check this

Answer (score 4):

In your WebApplicationInitializer, You can use following code:

```
    com.github.greengerong.PreRenderSEOFilter seoFilter = new com.github.greengerong.PreRenderSEOFilter();
    FilterRegistration.Dynamic filter =  container.addFilter("prerender", seoFilter);
    filter.setInitParameter("prerenderToken", "<YOU TOKEN>");
    filter.addMappingForUrlPatterns(null , true, "/*");
```

Answer (score 0):

I want to contribute the Spring Boot version for Aamirs solution.

```
@Configuration //instead of @SpringBootApplication 
@EnableAutoConfiguration //instead of @SpringBootApplication
@PropertySource(value = { "classpath:application.properties" })
@EntityScan("de.dpt.persistence")
@ComponentScan("de.dpt")
@EnableJpaRepositories("de.dpt.persistence")
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Application.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext context) throws ServletException {

        PreRenderSEOFilter seoFilter = new PreRenderSEOFilter();
        FilterRegistration.Dynamic filter =  context.addFilter("prerender", seoFilter);
        filter.setInitParameter("prerenderToken", "<your token>");
        filter.addMappingForUrlPatterns(null , true, "/*");

        super.onStartup(context);
    }

}
```

Comment: That's not very idiomatic (and I'm not sure it even works). It also has some confusing and irrelevant references to JPA stuff that wasn't in the original question.